# JavaFX webview shows blank page when i run project in browser

Tags: javafx

I am trying to run own JavaFX web browser into browser like chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox etc. When I load URL in own browser then is showing blank page.

I followed the code

```
package web_browser;



public class Web_Browser extends Application {

    TabPane root;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {


        WebView browser = new WebView();

        Tab browserTab = new Tab("New Tab", browser);
        Tab addTab = new Tab("+", null);
        addTab.setClosable(false);        
        addTab.setOnSelectionChanged(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                addNewTab();
            }
        });
        root = new TabPane(browserTab, addTab);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Browser");
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
        stage.show();

    }
      final void addNewTab() {

            WebView browser = new WebView();
            Tab browserTab = new Tab("New Tab", browser);
            root.getTabs().add(root.getTabs().size() - 1, browserTab);
            root.getSelectionModel().select(browserTab);
            browser.getEngine().load("http://www.google.com");
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It's working fine when i run as standalone application.

Comment: hmm .. you don't load a page into the first tab: the newly added tabs are showing the google page just as expected. To fix on face value, load the initial page into the webView on the first tab. As an aside: in fx11 I kept getting bunches of "can't access" errors due to module restrictions, so had to add 10+ --add-opens to the graphics module ... which very much feels like a bug

Comment: as to the (unrelated to your question, they had just been showing up in my testing :) access problems: explicitly adding the web module at runtime helped (without additional add-opens)